# メールで送信する際にAttributeErrorエラー

Tags: python, excel

下記のxlsxのデータを読み込みメールで送信したいですが、
AttributeErrorのエラーが表示されます。
以下のエラーはどう直せばよいのでしょうか。

xlsxのデータ

```
 A       B     C         
アメリカ  1234個  66.7%　 
カナダ　 1234個　4.9%
```

エラー

```
['アメリカ 1234 66.7%']
['カナダ' 1234 4.9%']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/test/Documents/test/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    message = '\n'.join([f"{column}\n{data}\n" for column,data in row.iloc[values].iteritems()]) #error !
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

code

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib
import codecs
import pandas as pd

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('text.xlsx',data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

for row in ws["A1:C2"]:
    values = []
    for col in row:
        values.append(col.value)
        print(values)

account = "1223"
password = "1223"

to_email = "1223"
from_email = "1223"

subject = "Test"
message = '\n'.join([f"{column}\n{data}\n" for column,data in row.iloc[values].iteritems()]) #error !
#'\n'.join(values)
print(message)
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["To"] = to_email
msg["From"] = from_email

# メール本文
message = MIMEText(message)
msg.attach(message)

# 添付ファイルの設定
attach_file = {'name': 'test.jpeg', 'path': 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.jpeg'} # nameは添付ファイル名。pathは添付ファイルの位置を指定
attachment = MIMEBase('image', 'jpeg')
file = open(attach_file['path'], 'rb+')
attachment.set_payload(file.read())
file.close()
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=attach_file['name'])
msg.attach(attachment)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(account, password)
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

28行目のmessageを下記に直すとエラーなしで行きますが、
出力結果 `カナダ　1234 4.9%` １行しか取得できないです。

```
#'\n'.join(values)
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージにある通り、

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iloc'

`tuple` は `pandas.DataFrame` や `pandas.Series` とは異なる型ですので `iloc` メソッドを持っていません。記載されているソースコードを見ますと、以下の様にすれば同じ結果になるかと思われます。

```py
message = ''
for row in ws["A1:C2"]:
  for col in row:
    if col.column_letter == 'C' and col.data_type == 'n':
      col.value = f'{col.value*100:.1f}%'
    message += f'{col.column_letter}\n{col.value}\n'
  message += '\n'

print(message)
```

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。勉強になります。こちらも問題なく実行できました。